# InkScape - Creating mandalas, How to copy a object so that every action is duplicate to the siblings?

Tags: inkscape

I want to create mandalas with InkScape in a similar way described in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3wxrO_JSFs

Is there a way to copy (clone rotate) an object so that every action is duplicate to the siblings?

I'm a programmer, so scripting is an option.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=inkscape+clone+copy

Comment: As pointed @MichaelSchumacher, one way is using the [Tile clones](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Tiles.html) dialog (e.g. this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZLwVpeu2-g)). Can you tell us more about your efforts?

Comment: Check out the mandala work of Orge Kalodimas for further inspiration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYk9YfJuQUs

Comment: This looks like a spam

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rotate copies live path effect for this.

1. select all objects you want in your mandala, then do Path > Object to path (the effect only works with paths)
2. group the objects together (important for later editing, if you want to add more elements to the effect)
3. Path > Path effects > + > Rotate copies
4. Adjust parameters in the dialog
5. Adjust center of mandala with node tool on the canvas
6. Enter group by double-clicking to edit it further by adding and modifying its elements

[image: Rotate copies LPE]